# Missing equals sign and SQL statement ignored Oracle trigger?

Tags: oracle, triggers, syntax-error

Here is a trigger I'm writing, and it keeps saying I have a missing equals sign on line 8, and the sql statement on line 7 is ignored? Is there any reason why this is happening?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_ACTOR_STARRED
BEFORE INSERT ON film_actor FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE a_count NUMBBER(10);
BEGIN       
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO a_count
FROM V_ACTORS_STARRED
WHERE :new.actor_id = actor_id;
    IF a_count > 0 THEN
    UPDATE film 
    SET rental_rate := rental_rate * 1.10
    WHERE  :new.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
    AND film.film_id = film_actor.film_id;
    END IF;
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remember to differentiate SQL from PL/SQL.

In a SQL UPDATE statement, `=` is used to assign. (Example `update tab set cola = 10`)

In PL/SQL procedural statement, use `:=` to assign. (Example:  `i := 10;` )

Your code below is embedded SQL so should use `=`, not `:=`

```
...
UPDATE film 
   SET rental_rate := rental_rate * 1.10
```

should be

```
UPDATE film 
   SET rental_rate = rental_rate * 1.10
```

Comment: Now I get ORA-00904: "FILM_ACTOR"."FILM_ID": invalid identifier  ---> does this mean I'm joining the tables incorrectly (I'm trying to update another table from this trigger)

Comment: Because the update statement is incorrect. There is no clue of `FILM_ACTOR` table.

Comment: @user3603183 - You also have a typo: `DECLARE a_count NUMBBER(10);`

Comment: @user3603183 - Even though you created the trigger on FILM_ACTOR, you can't use it like that in the trigger unless you name it properly in the SQL statement, in a join, just like you would write it outside of a trigger. To refer to the specific record being inserted, you use `:new`